# Pulling data from Object into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, object, dataframe, for-loop

I currently have an class designed to create a historical time series w/ various functions embedded inside.  I have created an object that holds a time series and use the code below to print the data held within the object:

```
for x in myobjectx.ts_data:
    print(x.Symbol, x.Date, x.Price)
```

I am trying to move this data into a dataframe with the code below so that I can run some more analysis on it .  When I run the code below, I get a dataframe w/ one column and all the data is various iterations of my object.

Can someone pls advise how to move the data in the object into a dataframe?

```
df = []
for x in myobjectx.ts_data:
    df.append(myobjectx.ts_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pandas DataFrame from list of dicts like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'symbol': x.Symbol, 'date': x.Date, 'price': x.Price} for x in myobjectx.ts_data])
```